# MySQL connection within a PHP function overwrites existing connection (other database) - how can I prevent this?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

We open a MySQL connection to host_**1** at the beginning of our script. Somewhere in between, we call a function that opens & closes a connection to host_**2** (function retrieve_information_from_host_2).

Unfortunately, the **code after the function** call **still uses the connection** of the function (**host_2**).

We need it though to **continue with the preceding connection** host_**1**.

```
<?php

function retrieve_information_from_host_2($host_2, $username_2, $password_2, $database_2) {
    $connection = mysql_connect($host_2, $username_2, $password_2);
    if($connection) {
        if(mysql_select_db($database_2)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1;";
            $erg = mysql_query($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($erg);

            return $row;
        }
        mysql_close($connection);
    }
}

if(mysql_connect($host_1, $username_1, $password_1)) {
    if(mysql_select_db($database_1)) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1;";
        $erg = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($erg); # CORRECT - This returns data from host 1

        $row_host_2 = retrieve_information_from_host_2(); # CORRECT - This returns data from host 2

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2;";
        $erg = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($erg); # WRONG - This returns data from host 2 instead of host 1
    }
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

We have tried almost every combination by giving each connection a name

```
$connection_1 = mysql_connect($host_1, $username_1, $password_1);
...
mysql_close($connection_1);
```

and closing them explicitly, etc.

Nothing helps. Can someone give us a solution to this problem?

PS: We are bound to this approach (functions) and can't use classes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Inside of the interrupting functions, have you tried closing the connection you don't want to use, and then reopening it at the end of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass your connection link identifier as second argument.

For example:

```
$connection1 = mysql_connect($host_1, $username_1, $password_1);
$connection2 = mysql_connect($host_2, $username_2, $password_2);
mysql_query('Query',$connection1);
mysql_query('Query',$connection2);
```

Answer (score 4):

See manual for [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for second parameter link_identifier (The MySQL connection)

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by
>   mysql_connect() is assumed.

You also should use mysqli instead of the old mysql.